# Storing and Retrieving RichText Content to/from SQL Database in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, rich-text-editor

I have a need to allow users the ability to add formatted text into a `<textarea>` control. I found a JQuery plug in ([Rich Text Editor](https://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Rich-Text-Editor-jQuery-RichText.html)) that creates the editor. Is there anything special I need to do to the data from the `<textarea>` control to store it in my SQL DB so that when it is retrieved and displayed in the `<textarea>` control it retains the formatting? I don't think it can be as simple as just passing the data to the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the formatted data directly to the SQL DB. When querying these data from SQL DB, the data comes with html tags. Minimal Rich Text Editor will automatically convert these formatted data.